# 401 responses with retryAfterSeconds in body for (throttled?) MS Graph API Requests

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

We're using the Microsoft Graph API to backup SharePoint and OneDrive changes.  Yesterday, quite a few of our requests started failing with a **401 response** and the body containing:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "serviceNotAvailable",
    "message": "Service unavailable",
    "retryAfterSeconds": 120
  }
}
```

To me this looks like a bug in the Graph API where it probably should be returning a **429 response** when a downstream request gets throttled, but instead treats it as a 401.

Not sure whether this is the intended behavior and how my app should deal with it (treat it like a 429?).  Or is this a regression that Microsoft will fix?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue last week and after countless conversations with Microsoft Support, I was able to solve the issue by increasing the “Server Resource Quota” on the “Site Collections” page of SharePoint Admin. You need to add more resource quota for the site “https://[your company name].sharepoint.com”. Also you get more total resource quota if you buy extra storage space for your Office 365 subscription. However, I do recommend Azure Blob Storage to be the backup place instead of SharePoint Online.